# Speeding up creation of nested structs

Tags: arrays, swift, struct

My code works as intended, I am just trying to speed things up.

I have a database table which contains millions of sensor measurements.
When I query the database for the measurements (sorted by the sensor's name) of the past 2 months, I get roughly 300,000 results.

I then proceed to step through the results and want to create nested struct objects from the data.
Here some shorter pseudo-code:

```
struct Measurement {
  var date: Int
  var temp: Double?
  ... 
}

struct Sensor {
  var sensorName: String
  var measurements: [Measurement]
}

var sensors:[Sensor] = []

...

for r in dbResults {
  ...
  let m = Measurement(date: r.date, temp: r.temp1, ... )

  if let index = sensors.firstIndex(where: { $0.sensorName = r.name }) {
    sensors[index].measurements.append(m)
  } else {
    sensors.append(Sensor(sensorName: r.name, measurements: [m]))
  }
}
```

This is however fairly slow. It takes about a minute for the loop to get done.
Is there a way to speed this process up? I am assuming `.firstIndex` takes too long.
I was thinking about creating the objects on parallel threads, but I wasn't sure how to best do that, without risking a race condition when checking the `.firstIndex`.

Thanks for any ideas

Comment: How many sensors are there in the data? If the 300,000 measurements are spread across, say, 10 sensors, I doubt `firstIndex` takes too long. Did you use Instruments to check _what_ takes too long?

Comment: Definitely agree with the above point. Of course, if there are thousands of sensors, then `.firstIndex(where:)` is inefficient. You can make use of the facts that they are sorted, and only look at the last index, instead of searching for first matching. It might also make sense to reserve the space ahead of time for the arrays, instead of progressively grow them. A lot depends on the distribution of the data

Comment: The number of sensors varies, but most of the time there are 4,000-6,000. Will try the `last` idea. How does one reserve the space in swift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change storage to dictionary

```
var sensors:[String: Sensor] = [:]

...

for r in dbResults {
  ...
  let m = Measurement(date: r.date, temp: r.temp1, ... )

  sensors[r.name, default: Sensor(sensorName: r.name, 
      measurements: [])].measurements.append(m)
}
```

Comment: didn't know you could have a default value for an array element. This is perfect and solves the speed issue. Wonderful! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Don't rewrite `Dictionary(grouping:by:)` yourself. Somebody else maintains that for you for free!!

Put that `var` here while you're at it:

```swift
let sensors = Dictionary(grouping: dbResults, by: \.name).map {
  Sensor(
    sensorName: $0,
    measurements: $1.map { .init(date: $0.date, temp: $0.temp1) }
  )
}
```